# fetch API getting the specific message from res.json({msg:"error...."})

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I am following a tutorial that uses axios for catching the specific error from the server but I can't catch the specific error using fetch.

```
 fetch("http://localhost:4000/snackhub/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password,
        }),
      })
        .then((res) => {
          let json = res.json();
          if (res.status == 200) {
            return json;
          } else {
            //what should i do here
          }
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          localStorage.setItem("auth-token", data.token);
          dispatch(fetchUsers());
          setUser({ email: "", password: "" });
          history.push("/");
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.msg);
    }
```

here are the examples of error in the server that I needed to get

```
 const { error } = await logInValidation(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).json({ msg: error.message[0].details })

if (!passwordVerified)
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "password is incorrect" });
```

Comment: in your `.then` try adding `const {errors} = json` and logging the errors. if the server is delivering a 200 and passing the error, it won't hit the `catch`

Comment: then what should i do with the errors sir?how should i use it?

Comment: is this even a valid javascript? the structure should be like this: `.then((data) => {}).catch((err) => {});

Comment: oops i mess that up thanks i didnt notice

Answer (score 0):

You can do: `.then(res => (!res.ok) ? res.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e)) : res.json());`